# Python : 'Turtle object has no attribute Turtle' error for seemingly no good reason

Tags: python-turtle

```
#this is a test

import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

turtles = []

def turtle_new(turtle_pos):

    new_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    turtles.append(new_turtle)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(turtle_pos)

for i in range(5):

    turtle_pos = (0, 0)
    turtle_new(turtle_pos)

for turtle in turtles:

    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle_pos = (turtle.position)
    turtle_new(turtle_pos)



loadWindow = wn

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: P.S.    turtle.position() not turtle.position

Answer (score 0):

I believe the specific error you're getting is due to this code:

```
for turtle in turtles:

    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle_pos = turtle.position()
    turtle_new(turtle_pos)
```

You were using the *module* name `turtle` in your code and now you've added the *variable* name `turtle` -- instead name the iteration variable something else:

```
for yertle in turtles:

    yertle.forward(100)
    turtle_pos = yertle.position()
    turtle_new(turtle_pos)
```

Now the code should run.  Though still not make much sense as it's augmenting `turtles` while looping over `turtles` so you end up with an *infinite loop*.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, thanks. As for the code, it's just meant as an example, it doesn't really have a purpose so it doesn't really change anything if it's an infinite loop.